# Webscrapping Using NodeJs output retrieving base64 images

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

So l have been trying webscrapping using node js, I attempted to scrape the nike website, l managed to retrieve all the data but the images are coming out as base64.

this is the selector from the nike website:

```html
<img alt="Nike Air Max Dn Men's Shoes" class="product-card__hero-image css-1fxh5tw" height="100%" loading="eager" sizes="" src="https://static.nike.com/a/images/c_limit,w_592,f_auto/t_product_v1/f50070d2-77a3-4213-aebf-9371d9759548/air-max-dn-shoes-q51Wwn.png" width="100%">
```

Below is the output:
[
Scraped Shoes:
{
name: 'Nike Air Max Dn',
price: '$210',
color: "Men's Shoes",
image: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7',
href: 'https://www.nike.com/ca/t/air-max-dn-shoes-q51Wwn/DV3337-008'
},
{

](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGWYy.png)

Below is my code and l have tried changing the selectors and nothing seems to work:

```
async function scrapeShoes(url) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const html = response.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);
      const shoes = [];

      $('.product-card').each((index, element) => {
        const name = $(element).find('.product-card__title').text().trim();
        const price = $(element).find('.product-price').text().trim();
        const color = $(element).find('.product-card__subtitle').text().trim();
        let image = $(element).find('.product-card__hero-image').attr('src');
        const href = $(element).find('.product-card__link-overlay').attr('href');

      
        const shoe = { name, price, color, image, href };
        shoes.push(shoe);
      });

      console.log('Scraped Shoes:', shoes); 
      return shoes;
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Failed to retrieve data. Status code: ${response.status}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('Error fetching data:', error);
  }
}

const targetUrl = 'https://www.nike.com/ca/w/new-shoes-3n82yzy7ok';
scrapeShoes(targetUrl)
  .then(() => {

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error scraping website:', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image of all the products is displayed thanks to an HTTP request that occurs when the web page loads via Javascript.

When you make an HTTP request, Javascript is not executed, so the DOM returned to you is devoid of information, as in your case.

To make scraping more efficient and to avoid libraries that manipulate the DOM like `Cheerio`, I recommend you to use directly this API that I found by analysing the website:

https://api.nike.com/cic/browse/v2?queryid=filteredProductsWithContext&language=en-GB&country=CA&channel=NIKE&path=/ca/w/new-shoes-3n82yzy7ok

It returns a JSON object containing all the products with all the information you need.